# Branch cuts of $\log(z^2-1)$ for unusual principal values

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, branch-points

Say we got a multivalued function
$$\log(z^2-1)\equiv\log(\xi(z)).$$
Usually, we would choose principal values such as $\arg\xi(z)\in[0,2\pi)$ or $\arg\xi(z)\in[-\pi,\pi)$. In order to find the branch cuts, for instance, for the $1^{\text{st}}$ one, we'd then need to impose $\arg\xi(z)=2\pi k$, namely,
$$\mathfrak{Re}\{\xi(z)\}=x^2-y^2-1>0$$
and
$$\mathfrak{Im}\{\xi(z)\}=2xy=0.$$

From both these conditions we'd finally find that the branch cuts are described by $y=0$ and $|x|>1$ (basically, $\mathbb R-(-1,1)$).

I then thought whether I could use the same methodology to find branch cuts for other, less common, principal values such as $\arg\xi(z)\in\left[-\frac{7\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$:

We'd impose $\arg\xi(z)=-\dfrac{7\pi}{4}+2\pi k$, that is,
$$\mathfrak{Re}\{\xi(z)\}=x^2-y^2-1>0$$
and
$$\mathfrak{Im}\{\xi(z)\}=2xy>0.$$

We can finally conclude that $\sqrt{x^2-1}>|y|$ and that either $x,y>0$ or either that $x,y<0$, meaning, if I understand correctly, that the branch cut isn't just a line, but a domain? How'd something like this be represented graphically? Would this be it?
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rr8nkw3a8c .
Does all of this make any sense at all?

Comment: Briefly, branch cuts are arcs, not regions. <> What may help here is to think of a branch of $\log(z^2-1)$ as a holomorphic function $f$ satisfying $\exp(f(z)) = z^2-1$ and having a "maximal" domain, i.e., so that no holomorphic extension has a properly larger domain. Branch cuts are arcs it suffices to remove to get a holomorphic, single-valued $f$. <> Branch cuts are not determined by the formal expression $\log(z^2-1)=\log(z+1)+\log(z-1)$, but typically by what purpose one has in mind, such as a particular line integral. Here, picking a single branch of $\log$ might not be optimal.